# How to show strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber editable with the mobile claim as default value?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm new in Azure Ad B2C custom policies.

In case of email local account connect I could solve to pass a default value for email claim. The api.localaccountsignup mechanism made it readonly and hide the Send Verification button what I could solve from JavaScript.

In case of phone local account I pass the mobile value for strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber:

```
<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="mobile" PartnerClaimType="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
```

But the api.phonefactor mechanism hid the phoneEntry that contains the code selector and number input:

[image]

Instead of it adds:

[image]

It looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible to show it via phoneEntry element? Currently the phoneEntry is removed from HTML so I can't show it.

So finally I would need this view and the strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber should bepre-filled mobile claim value.

[image]

I would much appreciate your suggestions, ideas, help. Thank you

Comment: I reviewed @ChrisPadgett answers on  some similar issue, but there was not a requirement that the input needs to be editable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56672180/how-can-i-read-the-mobile-value-from-a-b2c-user-record-and-transform-it-to-a-str

Comment: Can you explain the scenario in better detail to avoid an answer with security issues? I.E., whats the user doing to get to this screen, sign-up? Change phone number? is the phone number used for MFA in this flow?

Comment: @bolt-io The user is logged in, and wants to add phone number as local identity to be able to log in with it later on. In our AD the user already have the mobile attribute completed, and we would like to use that one for prefill when the user tries to connect his phone number in the flow.